# Can we say "Most Legendariest"?

Tags: superlative-degree

I want to know if this sentence is correct. Can we say "Most Legendariest ....."? If not, what is the alternative I can use? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is 'Legendariest' used, in some game, say? Are you trying to form the superlative of 'legendary'? It doesn't grade.

Comment: I know I would have trouble saying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the suffix “est” replaces the word “most” just like “er” replaces “more”. They are not used together. Some people may use it in a nonsensical or ungrammatical way for humorous emphasis. But, most native English speakers will count such a phrase as facetious hyperbole.

For example:

> That 600 pound woman is the absolute very most fattest person that I have ever seen in my entire life.

Plus, I don’t think legendariest is an official English word. If it is, it is unnatural to hear and speak. And, it has fallen out of common usage.